# Java method with two interdependent generic type constraints

Tags: java, generics, type-constraints

Not sure how to put it in words, so I'll just start with the code I currently have:

```
// "root type" for all resources
// fixed
public class ResourceClassA
{ }

// "base type" for all resources for a specific domain
// fixed
public class ResourceClassB extends ResourceClassA
{ }

// specific resource type
// can be derived from further but don't think that matters here
// not fixed but heavily constrained in other ways
public class ResourceClassC extends ResourceClassB 
{ }

// only needed for a negative example below, irrelevant otherwise
public class ResourceClassD extends ResourceClassB 
{ }

// fixed
public class Remote
{
    public <T extends ResourceClassA> Set<T> read(Class<T> baseType, Class<? extends T> subType);
}

// semi-fixed: read() signature can be modified
public interface AbstractRemoteAccess<T extends ResourceClassA>
{
    Set<T> read(Class<? extends T> clazz);
}

// semi-fixed: read() signature can be modified
public class SpecificRemoteAccess<T extends ResourceClassA> implements AbstractRemoteAccess<T>
{
    private Class<T> _baseType;
    private Remote _remote;

    public Set<T> read(Class<? extends T> clazz)
    {
        return _remote.read(_baseType, clazz);
    }
}

// not fixed
public class ConsumerClass
{
    public void doSomething(AbstractRemoteAccess<ResourceClassB> remoteAccess)
    {
        Set<ResourceClassB> rawObjects = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class);

        Set<ResourceClassC> castedObjects = rawObjects.stream()
                                                      .map(c -> (ResourceClassC) c)
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

All classes marked with *fixed* cannot be changed, they are provided as is - vice versa for *not fixed*. Class *SpecificRemoteAccess* is the one I'm looking to change: I would like the *read()* method to

- not return its result as *Set* but as a *Set<>* of generic type matching *clazz*
- so that the caller does not have to cast the method's result, see *ConsumerClass.doSomething()*
- and all of this without loosing type-safety

The easiest way I saw was to do

```
Set<V> read(Class<V extends T> clazz)
```

but that produces this error:

```
Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <V, T>
```

which, if I'm interpreting it correctly, means the compiler is treating *V* & *T* as separate type arguments for *Class* which doesn't match its definition.

Next I tried adding a second generic type *V* and using it as generic type for the return type of *read()*. I started with

```
<V extends T> Set<V> read(Class<? extends T> clazz)
```

which doesn't constrain *V* to *clazz* at all, meaning both of these will be accepted by the compiler

```
Set<ResourceClassC> correct   = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class);

Set<ResourceClassD> incorrect = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class);
```

The type declaration for *incorrect* is semantically wrong but syntactically fine. So I tried to constrain *V* based on *clazz* but the only solution I could think of is

```
<V extends T> Set<V> read(Class<V extends T> clazz, Class<V> classV)
```

which does, somewhat, fix the problem from above:

```
// compiles
Set<ResourceClassC> correct = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class,
                                                ResourceClassC.class);

// error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<ResourceClassC> to Set<ResourceClassD>
Set<ResourceClassD> incorrect = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class,
                                                  ResourceClassC.class);
```

but not only does it make the *read()* call cumbersome (users will be wondering why they have to pass the same info twice) but also error prone:

```
// compiles
Set<ResourceClassC> correct = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class,
                                                ResourceClassC.class); 
// type error
Set<ResourceClassD> incorrect  = remoteAccess.read(ResourceClassC.class,
                                                   ResourceClassC.class);

// compiles but will cause run-time cast failures
Set<ResourceClassD> incorrect2 = remoteAccess.readAndCast2(ResourceClassC.class,
                                                           ResourceClassD.class);
```

Given consumer-side developers are faced with hundreds of resource classes like *ResourceClassC*, making *read()* error prone simply is no option.

Would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: Where is type `Remote`?

Comment: @Michael: Fixed typos, thanks!

Comment: @Michael: I doubt "class Remote" is relevant here, it's simply another class in the call-chain of read(). Its "read()" method behaves exactly as is used by "SpecificRemoteAccess.read()" - and it's also "fixed" so I can't change it.

Comment: It's relevant because if you want anyone to try to reproduce this, they'll need to know the signature.

Comment: @Michael: Fair enough, added "class Remote". Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I think you just want `<V extends T> Set<V> read(Class<V> clazz);` right?

Comment: @Michael: Friend of mine also suggested this just a moment ago, will try it out. Compiler seems to be happy. I'll try to put it in and see what happens. Would you please formulate your comment as a reply in this thread so I can mark it as answer if your suggestion solves my problem (which I suspect it does) ?